# How do I convert this while loop into a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I am supposed to write code that multiplies numbers between 0 and 10 by 2 and 10. It is supposed to use a for loop. I was able to come up with this as a while loop, but anything I try to convert gives me a bunch of errors. The while code I have posted works, it just needs to be in for loop format.

```
while(numberCounter <= 10)
{
 byTen = numberCounter * 10;
 byTwo = numberCounter * 2;
 System.out.println(numberCounter + "\t" + byTwo + "\t" + byTen);
 numberCounter++;
 }
```

This is the whole problem:

```
// NewMultiply.java - This program prints the numbers 0 through 10 along
// with these values multiplied by 2 and by 10.
// Input:  None.
// Output: Prints the numbers 0 through 10 along with their values multiplied by 2 and by 10. 

 public class NewMultiply
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {

  String head1 = "Number: ";
  String head2 = "Multiplied by 2: ";
  String head3 = "Multiplied by 10:  ";           
  int numberCounter = 0;   // Numbers 0 through 10.
  int byTen;     // Stores the number multiplied by 10.
  int byTwo;          // Stores the number multiplied by 2.
  final int NUM_LOOPS = 10; // Constant used to control loop.

  // This is the work done in the housekeeping() method
  System.out.println("0 through 10 multiplied by 2 and by 10" + "\n");

  // This is the work done in the detailLoop() method
  // Write for loop

    // This is the work done in the endOfJob() method
            System.exit(0);
} // End of main() method.

} // End of NewMultiply class.
```

I figured it out. Thank you all very much for your help. The problem was that I had (numberCounter <= 10) instead of using the initialized NUM_LOOPS. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you looked at the documentation or a tutorial on `for` loops? If you have the answer will be pretty obvious to you. Start with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: The syntax is for(numberCounter = 1; numberCounter <= 10; numberCounter++) {...}

Answer (score 0):

The for statement has three parts, initializing variables, end condition and step operation.  You have all of those in your code

```
//initialize
int numberCount = 0;
...
//end condition
while(numberCounter <= 10)
...
//next step
numberCounter++;
```

you just need to put them together in your for statement and then put the remaining logic of your while loop in the braces after the for statement

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this and it executes what I want, however, it says I am not using a for loop?

```
for(numberCounter = 1; numberCounter <= 10; numberCounter++)
{
byTen = numberCounter * 10;
byTwo = numberCounter * 2;
System.out.println(numberCounter + "\t" + byTwo + "\t" + byTen);  
}
```

Comment: This should likely be an edit to your question rather than an answer. What is telling you that you aren't using a for loop?

Comment: Oh sorry. I am still learning how to work this. The program that is providing me feedback. It shows me getting the correct answer. But it says I am not using a for loop

Comment: try initializing the variable in the loop itself, something like `for(int numberCounter = 1; numberCounter <= 10; numberCounter++)`

Comment: It didn't change anything. The only thing I can think I need to include somehow is the NUM_LOOPS but I don't know where or how

Comment: You could say numberCounter <= NUM_LOOPS in the for statement,  Also, you could index the three lines inside the for loop.